# Why few numbers are getting added after calling serialize on an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, associative-array, key-value

I've an array titled `$aFilter`. Upon serializing it few numbers are getting inserted into it. I'm not understanding why did it happen? Why did it insert the numbers and in which pattern? Can someone please guide me what actually this serialize() does and generates such kind of output in an easy way?

Following is my program :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$aFilter = Array(
            'pages' => 1,
            'photo' => 1,
            'link' => 1,
            'event' => 1,
            'friend' => 1,
            'user_status' => 1,
            'poll' => 1,
            'quiz' => 1,
            'market' => 1,
            'apps' => 1
        );       
echo serialize($aFilter);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Output of above program is as follows :

```
 a:10:{s:5:"pages";i:1;s:5:"photo";i:1;s:4:"link";i:1;s:5:"event";i:1;s:6:"friend";i:1;s:11:"user_status";i:1;s:4:"poll";i:1;s:4:"quiz";i:1;s:6:"market";i:1;s:4:"apps";i:1;}
```

Please help me out by making me understand this thing.

Thanks.

Comment: This is how serialization works. [type]:[count]. so `a:10` means `array` with `10` keys. `s:5` means a `string` with `5` characters.

Comment: Take a look at [the amatomy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#66147) of a serialization.

Comment: In case the point is clear, may I write an answer?

Comment: @OfirBaruch: What does i:1 mean?

Comment: @AbraCadaver:Still I'm not clear, please elaborate.

Comment: Your array elements have values of 1 which is an integer so serialize encodes them as `i:1`.  What don't you understand, integer or 1?

Comment: Please notice, that I wasn't relate to the `i` case in my first comment so sorry for the confusion. `i` means `integer` type and `1` means the value and not the count. If your array values were `3` you'd see `i:3` in your serialized string.

Comment: @OfirBaruch:Still I'm confused. If you could put a detailed answer in an easy to understand language with some illustration it'd be better and easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets first understand the meaning of `serializing`.

[`Serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) , according to the manual:

> Generates a storable representation of a value

So we need to describe basically any value with a string in a way that we could also unserialize it later. So we're going to see a pattern that describes the serialized values which usually contains the `type of value`, `length` and `value` of course.

```
a:10{s:5:"pages";i:1;s:5:"photo";i:1;s:4:"link";i:1;s:5:"event";i:1;s:6:"friend";i:1;s:11:"user_status";i:1;s:4:"poll";i:1;s:4:"quiz";i:1;s:6:"market";i:1;s:4:"apps";i:1;}
```

Let's break your serialized string and compare it to your serialized object.

`a:10` - `a` stands for `Array` (`$aFilter = Array()`) and the number `10` represents the number of elements in the array.

`s:5:"pages"` - `s` stands for `String`, `5` stands for the length of the value - since it's a string we can say that this is a amount of characters in the string. `"pages"` is the value itself. (Same for `s:5:"photo"`, `s:4:"link"`, etc.)

`i:1` - `i` stands for `Integer` (number) and `1` is the value.

For instance, if instead of `'pages' => 1,` you had `'bla' => 4,`
the specific serialized part would be: `s:3:"bla";i:4;`
The "s" and "i" stay the same as we didn't change the type of the values,
but instead of `5` we have `3` since `bla` has 3 characters comparing to `pages` with 5, and instead of `i:1` we have `i:4` since now the value of that key is `4` and not `1`.

In order to understand this part we need to notice that the we're serializing an array. So the engine needs to understand which part is the key and which part is the value. `$array = array($key => $value)`;

In serialized string you'll notice that: 
`s:5:"pages";i:1;`
`s:5:"photo";i:1;`
it's just a matter of order, first comes the `key` and then the `value`, and over again.(separated with `;` of course).

I have to mention the link that @svengaly attached
which explain the whole "anatomy" of the serialization string. It's recommended to overview it if you're interested in further explanation and other scenarios.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#66147

Answer (score 0):

Your serialized array is read as follows:

```
a:10:{       // array: 10 elements
s:5:"pages"; // string: 5 characters, value "pages"
i:1;         // integer: value "1" (no number of digits is used for integers)
```

and so forth